# Postgres custom parallel aggregation extension in C, shared state?

Tags: c, postgresql, postgresql-12, postgresql-extensions

I am creating a Postgres C extension that is a parallelized aggregate function. Is there any way I can share the state, or any any state/memory-block I choose,  among all the workers? I dont want each worker process to have its own copy, I want a global copy for everyone.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would create a shared memory segment. You have to make sure that the area is destroyed afterwards (even if there is an error or other interruption), else you will leak memory.

Comment: May I get an example please?

Comment: Register an "at exit" function. I cannot be bothered to write an aggregate function in C.